# Is there a time limit to undeleting my own deletable questions?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, undelete

I refer to only [questions that fulfill](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions):

> Users can delete their own questions if the question:
>
> - has zero answers
> - has only one answer, but that answer has no upvotes
> - has no bounties that were awarded to any answer that isn't already deleted

Any time limit after I delete my question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can undelete the post at any time, but the posts will only show up in the "recently deleted posts" section of your profile for 60 days.  If it's older than that you'll have to know the URL of the question in order to get to it, to then undelete it.